# Plugin migration - how to handle count in php8.1

Tags: plugin-development, craft4

I am trying to migrate a plugin from Craft 3 to Craft4 .
The plugin basically checks the entry for a pdf asset and create a thumbnail asset from the PDF using Imagick to save with the entry.

I use to check for the presence of a thumbnail by doing :

```
$thumbs = $entry->pdfThumbnailImage;

if(count($thumbs) > '0'){
 //more checking code
}
```

Since php8.1 count above returns:

```
count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, craft\elements\db\AssetQuery given
```

I am super daft and rusty and wondered how other people are handling the change in count to check for a custom field asset.

Answer (score 2):

```php
$thumbs = $entry->pdfThumbnailImage->all();

if(count($thumbs) > 0){
 //more checking code
}
```